# A way to get project dependencies (as classes not .jars)

Tags: java, dependencies

Does anyone know of a way to get the exact class dependencies of a project (not which jars it depends on)? Then to find these dependencies in the jars in your classpath.

For instance if I use `StringUtil` and `RestTemplate` from apache-commons and Spring I'd like to see something like:

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.class -> M2_REPO/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.5/commons-lang-2.5.jar
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.class -> M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-web/3.2.1.RELEASE/spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
```

Thanks,

Comment: It goes without saying, but I just want to mention that I'm looking for a lib/tool that does this.

Comment: If you were using Groovy it would as easy as using [Grape](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape).

Comment: This comment really doesn't help me :)

Comment: That's why it is a comment and not an answer ;-) But you could mix groovy and java to accomplish what you want.

Comment: OK now I'm interested :) Could you give a bit more detail ?

Comment: Here's one link: http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-dynamic-language

Comment: And here's the official [Spring Dynamic Language Support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/dynamic-language.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely have a good look at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in several ways with [Structure101](http://structure101.com/) and Restructure101. For example here's an LSM in Restructure101 expanded to show which classes within jar icefaces-facelets-1_8 are used by icefaces-1_8_1:

[image: LSM showing class/jar dependencies]

Use "physical" breakout in the project settings to see the jars. You can even expand the classes to see which methods and fields are used.

If you prefer the info non-graphically you could use the [Collaboration](http://structure101.com/help/java/structure101/#perspectives/collaboration.html) view in Structure101. Free to use for a while - long enough to get your info.

Comment: Thank you very much this is perfect. I didn't know about the tool, it looks extremely useful.